# What does `pip install unstructured[local-inference]` do?

Tags: python, langchain

I was following a tutorial on langchain, and after using loader.load() to load a PDF file, it gave me an error and suggested that some dependencies are missing and I should install them using `pip install unstructured[local-inference]`. So, I did. But it is now installing a whole lot of packages. A whole lot of it includes some packages to do with `nvidia-*`. Can someone please explain what this command does? It took a good couple of hours for this command to complete.

Comment: How much detail do you want "explain what this command does"? It's installing the third party library [`unstructured`](https://pypi.org/project/unstructured/). See how to create a [mcve], and [edit] the question.

Comment: Which parts do you understand? Do you know what `pip` is? What `install` does? Do you know the difference between `unstructured[local-inference]` and `unstructured`? Critically, which of these are you actually asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the command that installs 'unstructured(https://pypi.org/project/unstructured/)' package. It's for pre-processing text documents such as PDFs, HTML and Word Documents.
So, it might be big and have many dependancies since it processes several types of documents.

Answer (score 4):

When you run "pip install unstructured," you simply install the "unstructured" package; no other dependencies are installed.

On the other hand, if you use the command "pip install unstructured[local-inference]", you additionally install the "local-inference" package as a dependency in addition to the "unstructured" package.

In situations when you must make predictions on data that is kept locally on your system, the "local-inference" package offers a collection of tools and utilities for doing local inference with machine learning models.

Additionally, as stated in the documentation, you may use pip install unstructured if you do not need to handle PDFs or pictures

Comment: Can you explain what "local-inference" typically does in the application? Or what operations that packages through `pip install unstructured` can't do?

Comment: Came here while setting up langchain :)

Answer (score -1):

the right method is:pip install "unstructured[local-inference]"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I installed unstructured already but I still had the same problem.

it seems like the correct way to do it is to do

`pip install "unstructured[local-inference]"`

instead of

`pip install unstructured`

here's the documentation that I got this info from:
[unstructured](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/ecosystem/unstructured.html)